# Can't render charts in angular 6

Tags: highcharts, angular6, angular2-highcharts

I ran the [highcharts demo app](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#installing) and it runs fine.

I created a variable called `chartOptions` in `app.component.ts`. This variable holds the json which I got from [the highcharts cloud](https://cloud.highcharts.com/create?q=4_cmG2WMT).
When I bind this variable to options in Highcharts, the chart is not rendering. There are no errors in the console as well. I am able to render chart using javascript (  `$('#wind-rose').highcharts(json from the above link)` )

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you send a simplified demo of your chart (codesandbox for example) or code example?

Comment: Pls add app.component.ts code specifically where you init chart.